# Error generating thread dump from console in weblogic

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x, thread-dump

I am trying to generate thread dump from weblogic console(Server-> -> Monitoring -> Threads -> Dump Thread Stacks.

I am getting below message: `Server must be running before thread stacks can be displayed.`

But, when I try to generate thread dump using `kill -3 <PID>`, it gets generated.

OS: Centos
Weblogic: WebLogic Server Version: 10.3.6.0

Can anyone please help me in understanding, why thread dump does not get generated from console and Why I am getting the message  saying server must be running.

NOTE: Server is in running state.

Comment: are you sure that you are trying to make dumps to a running server ?
Maybe you are hitting Admin Server with "kill"

Comment: I am getting dump that gives me information about the threads of application. I can see application classes mentioned in the thread dump(when I use kill).

Comment: I am using sun jdk. Should i use jrockit? only jrockit provides this functionality or this is present for sun jdk as well?

Comment: Hotspot has that feature as well, actually all JVM have it. Anyway the best approach is to use kill, because the text format obtained with that way can be parsed with tools to find out stuck threads. 

Tools like Threadlogic, Samurai, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As you are executing the Thread Dump command from Console, there might be an issue with AdminServer and managed server communication.

Console uses WLST to capture Thread Dumps and before generating thread dumps it will check Managed Server status. May be Admin Server unable to get current state of Managed Server hence you're seeing the error.

Recommended way to take Thread Dumps is OS command (kill -3 ) and from JDK tools, jstack for hostpot and jrcmd for JRockit. Thread Dumps taken from Console might not have lock related information and it might get truncated if thread dump is too long

Comment: try using  jstack {pid} > stack-trace.log

Comment: I am able to get thread dump from command line. Requirement is to get it from weblogic console itself.

Comment: In that case admin server unable to identify the status of managed server hence you are seeing the error. Can you check admin logs and paste here?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you was using JDK 7. It is a kind of bug in WLS 10.3.6.0 when using JDK 7. You can either downgrade the JDK to JDK 6 or [patch the weblogic](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/11119/core/RNINF/install.htm#BABEIIHI).